# Two description meta tags All in One SEO WordPress

Tags: customization, seo, plugin-all-in-one-seo

After installed All in one SEO plugin my home page has two descriptions. One by WordPress itself and one by All in one SEO plugin. Is there a simple way to remove WordPress one?

Please reconsider closing post as off-topic. Cos already done twice:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/two-description-meta-tags-all-in-one-seo-wordpress

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549769/two-description-meta-tags-all-in-one-seo-wordpress-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd need to see your site to be sure, but there's a very good chance it's your theme (not WordPress itself) that's setting the extra description field.  You can remove that from your `header.php` file and you should be set.  WordPress itself doesn't have SEO features like that built-in.

Comment: Here is the web site: http://indirmedenfilmizle.tv/ using mystique theme

Comment: Yes it was theme setting. Use optimization for search engines.